# How work with collections in YAML

Tags: collections, yaml

I have

```
init:
   test: yasha,grisha
      my: ${init.test[0]}
```

And it's now working.
How work with list/arrays in YAML?

Answer (score 3):

A list in YAML (normally called a sequence) can be specified in in block style:

```
a:
- 1
- 2
```

and flow style:

```
a: [1, 2]
```

both depicting a mapping with one key `a`, for which the value is the sequence/list consisting of elements `1` and `2`

The dashes before the elements in block style can, but do not have to be, indented further than the "parent" element

Comment: For example i have : test: [Grisha,Ivan] and name: (need Ivan from test). How i call it elemets? How i can get Ivan?